# Moving from one base to another java?

Tags: java, iteration, radix

I'm trying to create a program that reads in two bases from stdin and checks to see what's the smallest number in which both have repeating digits in it. It seems to be working fine for small bases but when I use larger bases I seem to be getting the wrong answer. e.g. giving it `3` and `50` it will find 22 as the smallest number where they both have repeated digits but i'm pretty sure 22 in base 50 is a single number.

What's the logic here that I'm missing? I'm stumped. Anything to point me in the right direction would be appreciated :)

My conversion method, this works for smaller bases but not larger it seems.

```
public static String converties(int number, int base)
{
    int remainder;
    ArrayList<Integer>remainders = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (number != 0)
    {
        remainder = number%base;
        remainders.add(remainder);
        number = number/base;
    }

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < remainders.size(); i++)
    {
        result+=Integer.toString(remainders.get(i));
    }

    result = reverseString(result);
    return result;
}

public static String reverseString(String result)
{
    String newResult = "";

    for (int i = result.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        newResult+=result.charAt(i);
    }

    return newResult;
}

public static boolean areThereRepeats(String value)
{
    ArrayList<Character> splitString = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (char c : value.toCharArray())
    {
        //if it already contains value then theres repeated digit
        if (splitString.contains(c))
        {
            return true;
        }

        splitString.add(c);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see where the the issue is occurring?

Comment: Note you can elide the `reverseString` call to `result = new StringBuilder(result).reverse().toString();` thus getting rid of that entire method.

Answer (score 1):

```
result+=Integer.toString(remainders.get(i));
```

In this line you add the remainder in base 10, so it will only work correctly if you find a match with `base <= 10`. Btw. It could be done very easily with `BigInteger` (if you don't want to do it yourself).

Otherwise:

```
 result += (char)(remainders.get(i) < 10 ? ('0' + remainders.get(i)) : ('A' + remainders.get(i) - 10));
```

This will work up to base 36.

Or just use `result += (char)remainders.get(i);` it will work up to base 256, but it won't be readable.

And I agree with Nathaniel Ford, it would be better to pass the ArrayLists. If you still want to get the String in the standard way you can make another function to which you pass the ArrayList and transform it with the 1st method shown here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It won't let me convert from Integer to char even if I cast it, nor will it let it cast to Character

Comment: @magna_nz, ok added brackets, should work now. Did you also correct the mistake described by Nathaniel?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this function:

```
public static boolean areThereRepeats(String value){
    ArrayList<Character> splitString = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (char c : value.toCharArray()){
        //if it already contains value then theres repeated digit
        if (splitString.contains(c)){
            return true;//Note that returning here only checks the first value that matches
        }
        splitString.add(c);
    }
    return false;
}
```

When you check to see if `splitString.contains(c)` it will return true if the array is length one. You aren't doing anything to check that the char `c` you're checking isn't comparing against itself.

Also note that Maraca has a point: the data structure you're choosing to utilize to record your remainders is flawed. `areThereRepeats` will work fine for checking if you assume that each new character represents a new remainder (or more specifically, the index into the base you're checking of the remainder you found). But why marshal all of that into a string in the first place? Why not pass the `ArrayList` to `areThereRepeats`?

```
public static boolean converties(int number, int base){
    int remainder;
    ArrayList<Integer>remainders = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (number != 0){
        remainder = number%base;
        remainders.add(remainder);//Saves the index of the remainder in the current base, using an integer base-10 representation
        number = number/base;
    }
    return areThereRepeats(remainders);
}

//Recursion ain't efficient, but...
public static boolean areThereRepeats(ArrayList<Integer> remainders){
    if (remainders.size() <= 1) {
      return false;
    }
    rSublist = remainders.sublist(1, remainders.size())
    if (rSublist.contains(remainders.get(0)) {
        return true;
    }
    return areThereRepeats(rSublist);
}
```

Comment: Trying this one but sublist returns a List<E> rather than an ArrayList which the function changes. I tried casting it to an arraylist but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: That's just a matter of changing the signature to `areThereRepeats(List<E> remainders)`, which is a better signature anyway since there is no reason to constrain it to an `ArrayList` or `Integer`s.

Comment: Tried doing that but still getting some error, `cannot find symbol <E>` 


    `public static boolean areThereRepeats(List<E> remainders){
        if (remainders.size() <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        List<E> rSublist = remainders.sublist(1, remainders.size());
        if (rSublist.contains(remainders.get(0))) {
            return true;
        }
        return areThereRepeats(rSublist);
    }`